# How is $\arctan2(\sqrt{h}, \sqrt{1-h}) = \arcsin(\sqrt{h})$?

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

According to this link here:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Hiversine distance is:
$2 \times r \times \arctan2(\sqrt{h}, \sqrt{1-h})$

Where $r$ is radius of the Earth.

Where as on this link:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#:~:text=The%20haversine%20formula%20determines%20the,and%20angles%20of%20spherical%20triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#:%7E:text=The%20haversine%20formula%20determines%20the,and%20angles%20of%20spherical%20triangles).

Hiversine distance is:
$2 \times r \times \arcsin(\sqrt{h} )$

so

$\arctan2(\sqrt{h}, \sqrt{1-h}) = \arcsin(\sqrt{h})$

How is this true?

Since:

$\arcsin(x) = 2 \arctan(\dfrac{x}{1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}})$

We would have

$\arcsin(\sqrt{h}) = 2\arctan(\dfrac{\sqrt{h}}{1 + \sqrt{1-h}})$

How do I go from here to $\arctan2(\sqrt{h}, \sqrt{1-h})$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try simply drawing a right triangle with sides $\sqrt{1-h}$, $\sqrt{h}$ and $1$?

Comment: Thank you Hans, I am out of practice for too long. I have drawn the triangle as you said and it made sense. That arcsin rule was misleading. 

If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: **NOTE** that the first link uses `atan2(y,x)` where [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) is the two argument inverse tangent function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be seen in a right triangle with sides $\sqrt{1-h}$, $\sqrt{h}$ and (by the Pythagorean theorem) $1$.